# Python - Scrape all class and print them out

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have been trying out to scrape a data from a HTML site basically that looks like

```
</div>
<div class="sizedata">
<a class="selectData" data-branch-on="1" data-size="11" data-ifno="105124" id="25096">

                    </a>
</div>
<div class="sizedata">
<a class="selectData" data-branch-on="1" data-size="12" data-ifno="173445" id="25097">

                    </a>
```

and I have been trying for hours and hours and I know that I am close but not enough!

So what I have been trying to do is

```
test = soup1.find('div', {'sizedata': 'data-size'})
print(test)
```

but what it gives it just empty saying "None" and I am just getting crazy now and I have no idea what to do anymore to scrape that out! Maybe there is something I am missing etc loop or so? Basically what I want to do is to have a print out etc

Data1 - data-size
Data2 - data-size
Data3 - data-size (for all tehse data-size is for each div's that there is basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class="sizedata"` in attribute.

**Ex:**

```
s = """
<div class="sizedata">
    <a class="selectData" data-branch-on="1" data-size="11" data-ifno="105124" id="25096"></a>
</div>
<div class="sizedata">
    <a class="selectData" data-branch-on="1" data-size="12" data-ifno="173445" id="25097"></a>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sizedata'}))
```

**Output**:

```
[<div class="sizedata">\n<a class="selectData" data-branch-on="1" data-ifno="105124" data-size="11" id="25096"></a>\n</div>, <div class="sizedata">\n<a class="selectData" data-branch-on="1" data-ifno="173445" data-size="12" id="25097"></a>\n</div>]
```

**Edit as per Comment** *(To find all 'data-size' attrs)*

```
print([item for item in soup.find_all() if "data-size" in item.attrs])
print([item["data-size"] for item in soup.find_all() if "data-size" in item.attrs])   #Just to get the data-size value
```

Comment: Oh that wasn't that hard, But now if I just wanna scrape data-size in th at case, What would that be in that case? ['data-size']?

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Hmm! I tried that but it gave me the whole div instead of just the data-size. Should it be like that?

Comment: Just add `'data-size': True` in the dictionary and use a list comprehension to get the values. `[x['data-size'] for x in soup.find_all(...)]`

Comment: @CDNthe2nd Updated snippet to get only `data-size` value